# Can you run a asp.net core 3.0 gRPC CLIENT in IIS? (possibly on Azure?)

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, grpc, asp.net-core-3.0

I've read a lot of conflicting information about this and it seems people are not 100% clear on what is possible and what is not.  I am certain that you cannot host a gRPC server app in IIS due to the HTTP/2 limitations.  The documentation is pretty clear.  However, I want to use IIS as a reverse proxy, with the internal side communicating using gRPC.  So the **client** would be in IIS, **not the server**.   I assumed that since the communication at this point (i.e. the back end) was not funneled through IIS, there would be no issue with this.  However, I keep seeing mixed answers.

I have created a dumb webapp that is hosted in IIS Express and can successfully post to my service running on Kestrel with gRPC.

Client code sample below.  The SubmitButton is just a form post on the razor page.

```
        public async void OnPostSubmitButton()
        {
            // The port number(5001) must match the port of the gRPC server.
            using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
            var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(
                              new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Server code is the boilerplate template for gRPC but looks like this:

```
namespace grpcGreeter
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        // Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
        // For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}


namespace grpcGreeter
{
    public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
        public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "Hello " + request.Name
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This works.  But, because I keep seeing mixed information saying it that it won't, I am not certain that once I go to deploy the client code (i.e. the reverse proxy), if I will run into problems.  I would like to use a host like Azure...but don't know if it's possible or not.

Any clarity on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any update on this? Did you manage to get the gRPC client running on IIS?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, we could use asp.net core mvc or razor page application as the client to call the grpc server.

But gRPC client requires the service to have a trusted certificate when you hosted the application on remote server IIS.

If you don't have the permission to install the certificate, you should uses HttpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback to allow calls without a trusted certificate.

Notice: this will make the call not security.

Additional configuration is required to call insecure gRPC services with the .NET Core client. The gRPC client must set the System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport switch to true and use http in the server address.

Code as below:

```
    AppContext.SetSwitch(
"System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        // Return `true` to allow certificates that are untrusted/invalid
        httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001",
   new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });
        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
        var response = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "World" });
```